# Rather than using crontab, can Django execute something automatically at a predefined time

Tags: django, tabs, cron, signals

How to make Django execute something automatically at a particular time.?

For example, my django application has to ftp upload to remote servers at pre defined times. The ftp server addresses, usernames, passwords, time, day and frequency has been defined in a django model.

I want to run a file upload automatically based on the values stored in the model.

One way to do is to write a python script and add it to the crontab. This script runs every minute and keeps an eye on the time values defined in the model.

Other thing that I can roughly think of is maybe django signals. I'm not sure if they can handle this issue. Is there a way to generate signals at predefined times (Haven't read indepth about them yet).

Comment: Why not use crontab? That's exactly what it's for, and it's very good at it.

Comment: A reason I can think of is easy user configurable periods, without having to translate what a user defines in a UI into a crontab line, and also running Django apps on Windows.

Comment: That's exactly the reason. I want to give the back end administrators (Which comprises of non technical staff) a form based configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record - there is also [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) which allows to schedule messages for the future dispatch. It's, however, a different beast than `cron`, as it requires/uses [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and is meant for message queues.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this recently and have found [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) which seems as though it would do what you want.

Edit: Also if you are not specifically looking for Django based solution, I have recently used [scheduler.py](http://code.google.com/p/scheduler-py/), which is a small single file script which works well and is simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've had really good experiences with [django-chronograph](http://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/).

You need to set one crontab task: to call the chronograph python management command, which then runs other custom management commands, based on an admin-tweakable schedule

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing is best solved using cron, not Django directly. Since it seems that you need to store data about your ftp uploads in your database (using Django to access it for logs or graphs or whatever), you can make a python script that uses Django which runs via cron.

James Bennett wrote a great article on how to do this which you can read in full here: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

The main gist of it is that, you can write standalone django scripts that cron can launch and run periodically, and these scripts can fully utilize your Django database, models, and anything else they want to. This gives you the flexibility to run whatever code you need and populate your database, while not trying to make Django do something it wasn't meant to do (Django is a web framework, and is event-driven, not time-driven).

Best of luck!